# How to calculate user churn by levels

Tags: sql, data-analysis

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    level,
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM
    dev
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level ASC;
```

It outputs the number of id's at each level:

| level | count_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4723602 |
| 2 | 4239623 |
| 3 | 4195459 |
| 4 | 3781344 |
| 5 | 3303071 |
| 6 | 2824263 |
| 7 | 3627376 |
| 8 | 2746447 |
| 9 | 3409989 |

You can see that count_id drops as the level increases. We need to write a query that finds how many id have fallen off at each level.

The answer should be:

| level | churn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ? |
| 2 | ? |
| 3 | ? |
| 4 | ? |
| 5 | ? |
| 6 | ? |
| 7 | ? |
| 8 | ? |
| 9 | ? |

I thought to do this: for example, subtract the count_id of the second level from count_id at the first level and divide by the number by the total number of id. But I don't know how to do it

WITHOUT WINDOW FUNCTION

Comment: Which dbms is this ?

Comment: Hi @aikkaaa, I have an answer for you without window function, it can be done with just join. Please have a try. At the same time, I want to point out one thing, in your example data, count_id deson't drop as the level increases. for example, level 8 -> level 9, it actually increase. that means the churn rate will be negative in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't use widow fictions, you can use a approach that works with out

```
SELECT
t1. id, CASE WHEN t2.count_id IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE  t2.count_id - t1.count_id END as diff_number
FROM (SELECT
    level,
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM
    dev
GROUP BY level) t1 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    level,
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM
    dev
GROUP BY level) t2 ON t1.level = t2.level+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which database you use. Also, as I'm not a native English speaker and I don't know the "churn" word, I had to ask translator what it is. Nothing related to databases, mathematics or anything similar so ... I'll try to *imagine* what you want.

This is Oracle syntax; hopefully, your database offers analytic functions as well. It is `lead` I'm using - it returns value that follows the one we're currently looking at (in current record).

If you use your query as a CTE (could be subquery as well, if you can't use CTE), then:

```
SQL> with your_query (lvl, cnt) as
  2    (select 1, 4723602 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 4239623 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 4195459 from dual union all
  5     select 4, 3781344 from dual
  6    )
  7  select lvl,
  8         cnt,
  9         lead(cnt) over (order by lvl) next_cnt,
 10         --
 11         cnt - lead(cnt) over (order by lvl) diff
 12  from your_query;

         LVL          CNT     NEXT_CNT         DIFF
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
           1    4,723,602    4,239,623      483,979
           2    4,239,623    4,195,459       44,164
           3    4,195,459    3,781,344      414,115
           4    3,781,344

SQL>
```

If you look at row #1:

- `cnt` is what your query returned as count of values related to `level = 1`
- `next_cnt` is value that is related to `level = 2`
- `diff` is - as it says and query shows - difference of these two values

Now, you can *divide it with total number of id* (whatever that "id" is), if you know that value.

Comment: I use clickhouse

Comment: Never heard of it before; Google says it supports CTEs and "window functions" (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/) so - I guess query I suggested *might* work (with some tweaking, perhaps).

Comment: clickhouse does not support window functions

Comment: Documentation (behind the link in my previous comment) says it does (unless I misunderstood it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CTE](https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-common-table-expression/), [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) operator and [coalesce](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) function to get the result you get.

1. First calculate the level cnt as usual
2. Then calculate the total cnt with all levels.
3. Join current_level and prev_level and calculate the difference.
4. Devide the result by total_cnt to get the churn value.

Here is the query:

```
With level_cnt AS (
SELECT
    level,
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM
    dev
GROUP BY level
),
total_cnt AS (
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM
    dev
)
SELECT
    c.level,
    (coalesce(p.count_id,c.count_id) - c.count_id) * 1.0 / t.count_id as churn
FROM
    level_cnt c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    level_cnt p
ON
    c.level = p.level+1
CROSS JOIN
    total_cnt t
ORDER BY C.level DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no gaps in level column we can do it by join the table with itself by level = level+1 to get data in one row, then its will be easy to subtract the count_id of the second level from count_id at the first level :

You will have to change the `select count(1) from mytable` by **the total number of id**

```
select level, count_id/(select count(1) from mytable) as churn
from mytable where level = 1
union
select t1.level, (t2.count_id - t1.count_id)/(select count(1) from mytable) as churn
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.level = (t2.level+1)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3hyLoSKb)